Need help in finding the title of a YA (possibly) fantasy book
My late dad told me about this book that he was reading pre-2020s (could be half a decade or more ago). I haven't had the chance to remember the book's title and its author but I remember a few stories about it told by my dad:

I know that the protagonist is a guy and the magic system is kind of pokemon-ish (?). Basically this kid or teen can control a monster (or something) and fight the enemy.
This one is what I distinctly remember from it. The protagonist saved a girl. When he saved her, her eyes changed color the same as the mc's eye. And it's said that it technically means that the girl is in love (?) with the guy and that they are (technically) married.

I don't remember too much about it because he told me about the book in a whim and went to talk about another story that we both know and talked about in length. One thing to note is that I might be wrong about my first point and it might be another story.

This is Furies of Calderon by Jim Butcher.
This synopsis mentions the eye-changing colour thing.

Tavi and Fade are attacked by Kord, the leader of Kordholt and a
slaver. During the fight, Bernard and Amara attack Kord when Fidelias,
Odiana, and Aldrick attack. Aldrick kills Kord's son Bittan and after
arriving, Isana floods the river. Bernard and Amara go one way; Tavi
and Fade a second, and Fidelias and Aldrick another; Isana, Odiana,
Kord, and Kord's oldest son Aric are washed to Kordholt. Tavi and Fade
are captured by a Marat Headman named Doroga. Odiana and Isana,
captured by Kord, are locked away and Odiana is raped. Bernard and
Amara continue to Garrison where they rouse the Legionares. Fidelias
and Aldrick go to the Marat leader Atsurak, who decides to invade
Garrison immediately. Tavi convinces Doroga to let him undergo a trial
that can stop the attack on Garrison. Tavi faces the trial with Kitai,
Doroga's daughter, and wins, saving Kitai's life in the process, and
undergoing some sort of bond with her which changes the colour of her
eyes to match his, although he does not understand the meaning of this
change.

and the Pokémon thing.

The story takes place in the Aleran Empire, which contains "crafters",
people who can control the elements: water, air, earth, fire, wood,
and metal, through a person's bond with an element's fury.


Wow.  You're probably right, but I would never have gotten here from the provided description.

@DavidW - I'm sure I've seen another post about the eye-colour-changing-because-she's-his-secret-wife thing somewhere (Reddit maybe?). Apparently it's pretty cringey.

The eyes are a psychic bond thing, not a secret wife thing.

Wow, thanks! That's exactly it! I vaguely remember the name 'Calderon' but I never connected the dots because I thought it's someone I know and not an integral part of the title XD. Thanks again, I should probably read it and get some familiarity of the book in memory of my dad.
